# Função não funciona com UseSubmitBehavior="False"

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Possuo esse button:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button11" runat="server" 
  Text="Cancelar" CssClass="btn btn-danger btn-block" 
  OnClick="Button11_Click" 
  OnClientClick="javascript:return confirm('Deseja cancelar toda a venda?');" 
 UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
```

Preciso que ele seja `UseSubmitBehavior="False"`, porém quando coloco para falso, ele não funciona o `confirm`, ele aparece o `alert`, porém independente se eu clico no ok, ou no cancelar, ele não faz nada, quando o `UseSubmitBehavior="true"` ele funciona corretamente, porém se alguém clica no enter, ele realiza o click desse `button`, como posso proceder?

Comment: Tem que tirar esse `UseSubmitBehavior="False"` e utilizar outra forma, o que realmente quer fazer?

Comment: Eu quero que se clicar enter em qualquer lugar do form, o click desse button não seja feito, pois é isto que está ocorrendo.

Comment: Tem alguma coisa errada no seu formulário coloque ele na pergunta!

Comment: Isso acontece por causa do  OnClientClick="javascript:return confirm('Deseja cancelar toda a venda?');"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faça assim

```
<asp:Button ID="Button11" runat="server" 
  Text="Cancelar" CssClass="btn btn-danger btn-block" 
  OnClick="Button11_Click" 
  OnClientClick="if ( ! UserDeleteConfirmation()) return false;"  />

function UserDeleteConfirmation() {
  return confirm("Deseja cancelar toda a venda?");
}
```

Comment: Funcionou certinho, obrigado.